# Rails Activesupport error in rpect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am beginner Ruby on Rails. I was following railstutorial.org to trying to do test but I am getting error related to activesupport. 
I am on Yosemite. I run command 'rails generate integration_test static_pages' to generate static_pages and after trying to run TDD for same. I run 'exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb' and I got error

```
/Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': No such file to load -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/rspec-rails-2.13.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:360:in `require_or_load'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:317:in `depend_on'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:233:in `require_dependency'
from /Users/pradeepkotwal1/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

Can you please help me

Comment: What tutorial are you actually following?  Also, can you show me the content of /Users/pradeepkotwal1/rails_projects/sample_app/spec/spec_helper.rb

Comment: I am using http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/static_pages

Comment: And what does your spec_helper.rb look like?

Comment: I have removed comments and now its shows ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"

  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true

  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

  config.order = "random"
end

Answer (score 0):

Your spec_helper.rb should look like this, I'm not sure if you pasted it wrong:

```
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
  ActiveRecord::Migration.check_pending! if defined?(ActiveRecord::Migration)
  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
    config.order = "random"
  end
```

Check it and try again.  If this doesn't work try backing up your Gemfile and replace it with:

```
https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app_rails_4/blob/master/Gemfile
```

then run

```
bundle install
```

then try again:

```
bundle exec rspec spec/requests/static_pages_spec.rb
```